# Displaying the content on a different html based on the primary key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django to create a site. I have Table called notice as below
    Models.py

```
class Notice(models.Model):
        Notice_No=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        Content=models.TextField(max_length=5000, help_text="Enter Owner Name")
```

I am using a for loop to display the all these fields on my template page as
Notice No, Content, Date of issue, Date of expiry. I have provided a hyperlink to the all the content values which take it to another HTML play with a proper notice formal of a CHS. Now what I wanna do is if I click on let's say notice of notice no-1. I only want to display the content of that notice on the next page. If I click on notice _no 2, it should only display the contents of that notice. I'm new to python so not sure how to do this. How do I go about this?
    Notice.html is the page that displays the table. Noticesoc.html display is where the content should be displayed.

views.py

```
def notices(request):
    Notice_all=Notice.objects.all()[:50]
    return render(
        request,
        'notices.html',
        context={'Notice_all':Notice_all}
    )
def noticesoc(request):
    Notice_all=Notice.objects.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'noticesoc.html',
        context={'Notice_all':Notice_all}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the primary key of the data you want to see in detail.

```
<td style="color:white; font-family:helvetica; font-size:15px;">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'noticesoc' Notice.pk %}">
                            Click here to view the contents</a>
                        </td>

url( r'^noticesoc/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'noticesoc')
```

Then in the view. Use `.get` to get the information Notice and then render it.

**Ex:**

```
def noticesoc(request, pk):
    Notice=Notice.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(
        request,
        'noticesoc.html',
        context={'Notice_all':Notice}
    )
```

Comment: this is my url.py file 
 urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('r^complaints',views.complaints, name='complaints'),
    path('r^notices',views.notices, name='notices'),
    path('r^maintenance',views.maintenance, name='maintenance'),
    path(r'^noticesoc/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.noticesoc, name='noticesoc'),
    path('r^registration',views.registration, name='registration'),

]  

i got this error when i tried your method- noticesoc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Comment: Updated snippet. use `def noticesoc(request, pk):`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Error=local variable 'Notice' referenced before assignment. Can you see my url.py(previous comment) and see if it's correct

Answer (score -1):

in reference to this ....
Still doesn't work. Error=local variable 'Notice' referenced before assignment. Can you see my url.py(previous comment) and see if it's correct

you will notice that the model name and the function name are similar hence instead of django differentiating the two it assumes them as similar with the first code to run as the model then the view function
try to use another name for your view function and call the name different and unique from the model name for instance

def noticesoc(request, pk):
**Notice=Notice.objects.get(id=pk)**
return render(
request,
'noticesoc.html',
context={'Notice_all':Notice}
)
use this instead

def noticesoc(request, pk):
note=Notice.objects.get(id=pk)**
return render(request,'noticesoc.html',context={'note':note}
*emphasized text*

Comment: Properly format blocks of code please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31399758)